# Android. Как отключить режим сна?

Tags: android

Когда аппарат подключен через кабель к компьютеру, то при нажатии на кнопку блокировки гаснет только экран а само устройство не засыпает. Как можно сделать так, что бы оно также не засыпало и при отсутствии соединения кабелем?